# Facebook 'Feed' dialog 'name' link not working

Tags: facebook

Here is my working code that successfully displays the Facebook 'Feed' dialog in a new window:

```
      <a class="fbShareToWall" 
        onClick='window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=103528099783xxx" 
        + "&link=http://www.thesite.com"
        + "&name=Please%20respond%20to%20the%20link"
        + "&caption=Just%20work"
        + "&description=Comeon%20work"
        + "&redirect_uri=http://www.thesite.com");'">Share on Facebook</a>
```

This successfully displays the Feed dialog in a new window.

Notice the '&name' parameter in the code above  -- on the Feed dialog it displays as:  **Please respond to the link**.

BUT if you click on it -- it does nothing, as if it's not a link.  But it is, in fact, a link.

The '**Please respond to the link**' looks like a link -- it is in a bold font and the letters are blue, while the other params -- the *'caption'* param which displays on the Feed dialog as 'Just Work', and the *'description'* param which displays as 'Comeon work' -- those are not in a bold font nor are they in blue color.  Just regular text, those two params.

So with my Feed dialog box open,  I right-clicked on the **Please respond to the link**  and selected 'Open link in a new window' and Firefox opens a new browser and the URL bar has the *http://www.thesite.com* which, as you notice, is how I set my &link parameter in the above code.  In other words -- Firefox has no problem navigating with the URL connected to my &name parameter.

Next, I checked and made sure Firefox was not blocking popups.  It wasn't.

I don't undersand why my "**Please respond to the link**" feed dialog  *&name* parameter:

- looks like a clickable link on the Feed Dialog box
- and upon being right-clicked, it can be opened in a new browser -- and navigates to the *&link* parameter successfully
- and yet does NOT do anything if you click on **Please respond to the link** on the Feed dialog.

Am I missing something in my Feed dialog code above?

What is the purpose of the *&name* parameter on that Feed dialog box?

Or what's the point of having the **&link** and **&name** paramaters appear to be a link on the Feed dialog but then NOT work when clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This save behavior exists when using the javascript sdk to publish, and I think that it's intended by facebook.

What you see in that dialog is only a preview of how it will look like when posted, and as a preview it's probably not supposed to act as the real thing.
This is probably the behavior so that the user will finish the publishing process with out being redirect to another page (same or different window/tab) by clicking on the items in the preview.

Comment: Well, it sounds like my code above must be okay then.  It's just a bit confusing to see a link and only access it by right-clicking.  I'll go with it, sounds like they are driving the car.  Thanks for letting me and others reading this about your experience using the js api and getting the same behavior, it proves the behavior is normal.

Comment: Not only the text link behaves like this, also the thumbnail picture which also is a link behaves the same in the display.

Comment: Shouldn't the link (and redirect url) be inside the facebook domain? Since you are building a facebook app, facebook expects the target of the message to be either an app or a page related to that app. So I don't think you can link to an external website. (Sorry to reply to an old thread, but it might help future searches.)

Comment: No, you can share non fb urls. It's in fb's best interest that people will share links.