# "See More" & "Name" link under Facebook feed dialog are not clickable

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have been working on Facebook feed dialog integration for my website. I am using JavaScript SDK. Although I got it working, I just noticed that "see more" in dialog box is not at all clickable. Same applies to "name" & "thumbnail". Couldn't find much details about this bug in Google except these two posts:
[Facebook 'Feed' dialog 'name' link not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250432/facebook-feed-dialog-name-link-not-working)
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/433691090008676/

Does anyone know any more details? Is this intended to behave this way by Facebook?

Thanks in advance!